# Getting error on using rake db:create command (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rake

I have just started with ruby on rails, have made a new rails project folder.
Now I am trying to use rake db:create command but am getting the following error.
Please help.

```
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /home/samsung/ruby/blog/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#initialize is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#initialize called from /home/samsung/ruby/blog/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/rdoctask.rb
Please install RDoc 2.4.2+ to generate documentation.
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- sqlite3

Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Please tell us what operating system you're on and how you installed Ruby so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the gem you want to use is added to your gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Then, to install the gems, from the command line in the app root:

```
bundle install
```

This will cause them to be automatically required, fixing the error of:

```
no such file to load -- sqlite3
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the final line of your output:

```
no such file to load -- sqlite3
```

It shows that it can't find the `sqlite3` file. This could be because the `sqlite3` gem is not installed. Try to find it with this command:

```
gem list sqlite3
```

If it doesn't come up, install it with this command:

```
gem install sqlite3
```

---

I think you may have installed an older version of Ruby as well. I would recommend using RVM and installing a newer version of Ruby, such as 1.9, rather than 1.8. See [this page](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) for information on how to do that.

Comment: I used rvm to install a new version of ruby. BUt it got installed in /usr/share and the older version is still there in /usr/lib

Comment: And when i check ruby --version it is showing the old version only.

Comment: @Abhinav, that's the point of the rvm. It allows you to switch between different versions of ruby, etc. Anyway, do `rvm use 1.9.2 --default` or whatever the version of ruby you want to use in the rvm. Assuming you installed other version of ruby. Use `rvm list` to see which versions you have, and then use the other command to switch to whichever you want.

Comment: Yes, use `rvm use 1.9.3 --default` to switch to that version of Ruby being your default.